# MapView doesn't load Current User Location and doesn't center / zoom on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios8.1

I am trying to show my current Location on a MapView. I added a Button to my Storyboard.

First problem: The Current Location is not shown on my screen.

Second problem: The MapView doesn't zoom to the Location if I click on the Button.

My ViewController.m :
(The Button Methods Name are: `getLocation` )

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import CoreLocation;


@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapview = _mapview;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender
{
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


// The sender here are a Button on my Storyboard, who should show the current device Location if i click on it.
-(IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender
{
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
    //NSLog(@"Koordinaten des Geräts: %@", mapview.userLocation.description );
    //[mapview setCenterCoordinate:mapview.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you testing it in iOS 8?

Comment: Have you implemented  CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods?

Comment: Yes and i also set the keys in the info.plist

Comment: No, how i can set CLLocationManagerDelegate and for what is it?

Comment: Can you access mapview as a property as you appeared to be accessing it as an ivar, that might solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;
}
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
}
```

And for zoom try this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapAllLocations;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

mapAllLocations.ZoomEnabled = true;
mapAllLocations.ScrollEnabled = true;
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;

zoomLocation.latitude =newLocation.latitude;
zoomLocation.longitude=newLocation.longitude;

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation,1000.0, 1000.0);
[self.mapAllLocations setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: and where in my Syntax should i add this Blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** on your info.plist file and it is required iOS 8 onwards, you can optionally leave its value empty. In the past, one could optionally include a 'NSLocationUsageDescription' key , a string explaining to the user for what the app planning to use location services. And now it has been split up into two separate keys (**NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** and **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**), and is now mandatory; if you call requestWhenInUseAuthorization or requestAlwaysAuthorization without the corresponding key, the prompt simply won't be shown to the user.

Please bear in mind, if you specify **requestAlwaysAuthorization** key but your app didn't use the locator always, preferably in the background, then you can face rejection from the apple during app store submission.

Comment: Yes i set the keys, and i see my own description too in the Alert View.